# How to Show a message at every five minutes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a `Learning Management web application`. in this application there is a web page name `test`. on this page registered user can give the test. What i want is that at every five minute on the test webpage it display a message like `five minutes pass` and after 10 minutes it display `10 minutes pass` and so on.

How can I implement this functioning **without using the timer clock**?

Comment: look at js setInterval

Comment: what u have tried?have u searched on google?https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww&ei=bBgcVIDqHo2VuASIxoLIDw&ved=0CBAQ1S4#q=javascript+function+every+x+seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = setInterval(function() { /*your message logic */ }, 300000);
```

Here,
300000 = 5 minutes in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <button id="start">Start Test</button>
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById("start");
el.addEventListener("click",function(){

    setInterval(function(){ 
     alert("5 more minutes Passed");
    },300000);
});
```